# how to convert every youtube link i have on my wordpress posts into embed?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, replace, youtube

i am using the latest version of wordpress , i have around 10000 post right now on my website.

i have a nice plugin that makes my website looks a bit more fancey but i need to ad a simple code to each featured image and each embeded youtube video i have in my posts (if i could pick user who add it too that would be perfect ! ) to get it to work

i know that youtube embed code is

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NrH9CqnzzRU?list=PLHPcpp4e3JVpXbtgyD-k-nCmwpbbMIHOh" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

what i need to do is to add

```
<div class="featuredvideo"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

so i want to add those things before and and after "XXXX" s

i am not a programer so please give me the code

i know that AJAX can search entire folder with code like

```
<button>AJAX</button>
<br>
<div id = "container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("sample.html",function(data){
    $("#container").html(data);
    })

});
```

which will just get html from a file but that is now what i want to do here.

please help me , give me a plugin or a code to work with

thank you

Comment: So you want to detect the youtube iframes and wrap them with that div?

Comment: yes that is what i want to do exactly !

Comment: Okay - no problem.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap the Youtube iframes with the div as required, just use this...

```
$(function() {
    $("iframe[src*=www.youtube.com]").wrap("<div class=\"featuredvideo\" />");
});
```

That will run when the document has finished loading.  It will find all iframes with the string `www.youtube.com` in the `src` attribute and wrap them in the required div.

Obviously, if you add any more iframes to the page later and it doesn't reload then you'll need to run that code again.  If you did just that then it would wrap the iframes in the div again, which would be wrong.  This will handle running the code multiple times...

```
function wrapYoutubeEmbeds() {
    $("iframe[src*=www.youtube.com]").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("featuredvideo")) {
            $(this).wrap("<div class=\"featuredvideo\" />");
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    wrapYoutubeEmbeds();
});
```

It simply checks to see if each iframe is inside something with the class `featuredvideo` and ignores it if it is.